# TCP connection fails at recv() function

Tags: sockets, tcp

I'm a newbie in socket programming.

I'm trying to interface in TCP between server and client by following a certain protocol.

After the connection is established, the communication starts by client sending a certain packet to the server. My program fails at the `recv()` function at client side.

Let me share you the client side of my code:

```
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0)
{
    printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
}

ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

iResult = getaddrinfo(LOCAL_IP, "8081", &hints, &result);
if (iResult != 0)
{
    printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next)
{
    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
                           ptr->ai_protocol);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        continue;
    }
    break;
}

MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET* ps8ptr = new MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET;
memset(ps8bufrecv, 0, DEFAULT_BUFLEN);
s32packetlen = sizeof(MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET);           
printf("size %d\n", sizeof(MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET));
iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, ps8bufrecv, s32packetlen, 0);        
if (iResult == -1)
{
    printf("Here !\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "recv Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
    return -1;
}
memcpy(ps8ptr,ps8bufrecv,sizeof(MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET));
```

And here is the server side of the code:

```
nErrorStatus = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
serv_sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if(serv_sock == -1)
{
    printf( "socket() Error..Error --> Code %d ", WSAGetLastError() );
    error_handling("socket error");
}
memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));

serv_addr.sin_family = PF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(CLIENT_PORT_NUMBER);

if(bind(serv_sock, (struct sockaddr*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) == -1)
{
    printf( "bind() Error..Error --> Code %d ", WSAGetLastError() );
    error_handling("bind error");
}
if(listen(serv_sock, 5) == -1)
{
    printf( "listen() Error..Error --> Code %d ", WSAGetLastError() );
    error_handling("listen error");
}

clnt_addr_size = sizeof(clnt_addr);
clnt_sock = accept(serv_sock, (struct sockaddr*)&clnt_addr, &clnt_addr_size);
if(clnt_sock == -1)
{
    printf( "accept() Error..Error --> Code %d ", WSAGetLastError() );
    error_handling("accept error");
}

MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET* ps8ptr = new MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET;
ps8ptr->header.msg_id = MSG_PDDAU_INFO_ID;
ps8ptr->header.msg_type = MSG_REQUEST_TYPE;
ps8ptr->time_enable = 0x01;
s32packetlen = sizeof(MSG_PDDAU_INFO_PACKET);
memset(ps8bufsend, 0, DEFAULT_BUFLEN);
memcpy(ps8bufsend,ps8ptr, s32packetlen);                    
iResult = send(clnt_sock, ps8bufsend, s32packetlen, 0);   
if (iResult == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "send Error Occurred %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
    return -1;
}
```

The code keeps failing at the first `recv`/`send` interface after the connection, and the error message looks like below.

Server side:

```
Time msg id : 5
Time setting failed
```

Client side:

```
recv Error Occurred Invalid argument (22)
```

I don't know what's the correct way to communicate in my case.

It'd be great if anyone can point out my problem here.

Comment: I'd put a `printf("ConnectSocket=%i\n", ConnectSocket);` just before the `recv()`, so you can check whether `ConnectSocket` is a valid socket handle or not.  My suspicion is that it is invalid, and that is why `recv()` is erroring out with errno set to "Invalid argument"

Comment: Your client code is not checking that the `socket()`/`connect()` loop is exiting with a valid `SOCKET` before calling `recv()`. That is the only invalid parameter which you could be passing to `recv()`. Initialize `ConnectSocket` to `INVALID_SOCKET`, and then add an `if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)` check after the loop exits.

Comment: Also, since this is clearly WinSock-oriented code running on Windows, you should be using `WSAGetLastError()` instead of `errno` to get socket error codes. You are doing that for all of the other socket API calls, but not for `recv()`. Also, there is no need for `ps8bufrecv` or `ps8bufsend` at all, you can recv/send `ps8ptr` directly instead (also, you are leaking `ps8ptr` on failure)

Comment: @Remy. When I've printed out the error message after using the recommended 'WSAGetLastError()', it says 'recv failed with error : 10054'. I don't have a clue to fix it. Do you have any more recommendations?

Comment: @Taki 10054 is `WSAECONNRESET`: "*Connection reset by peer.An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.*" That is not an error I would expect to see from this code, unless the server fails and closes the connection with the client.